# How to use unit test in backend-less app?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I create backend-less app with a unit test that test is a http get call, my problem is when I remove `ngMockE2E` module in main app and fake backend http get handler in app.run() every thing works fine but when add add `ngMockE2E` and fake backend http get handler in app.run() and then run test this error will be appear:

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
    createHttpBackendMock/$httpBackend.flush@C:/app-server-ui/libs/angular/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1779:1
    @C:/app-server-ui/test/signin.controller.test.js:35:7
    invoke@C:/app-server-ui/libs/angular/angular/angular.js:4523:14
    workFn@C:/app-server-ui/libs/angular/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2810:11
    angular.mock.inject@C:/app-server-ui/libs/angular/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2778:25
    @C:/app-server-ui/test/signin.controller.test.js:17:35
    @C:/app-server-ui/test/signin.controller.test.js:16:3
    @C:/app-server-ui/test/signin.controller.test.js:4:1
```

my test file is:

```
describe("SigninCtrl", function () {

  var $httpBackend, $controller, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler;
  beforeEach(module("app"));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $controller = $injector.get("$controller");
    $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when("GET", "/signin")
      .respond({username: "admin", password: "admin"});
  }));

  describe("auth user", function () {
    it("user pass must be admin", inject(function ($http) {

      var $scope = {};

      /* Code Under Test */
      var controller = $controller("SigninCtrl", {$scope: $scope});
      /* End */
      $http.get("/signin.py")
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.user = data.user;
        });
      $httpBackend.whenGET('/signin.py').respond({
        "user": {
          "username": "admin",
          "password": "admin"
        }
      });

      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect($scope.user).toEqual({username: "admin", password: "admin"});
    }));
  })
});
```

and my app run function is :

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(runBlock)
    .config(config);
  runBlock.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$httpBackend'];
  function runBlock($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $httpBackend) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/(\.html|\.svg)/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/signin.py').respond({
      "user": {
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I don't get why you use `$httpBackend` in your production code. It's for testing purpose only. And why are you doing an http request inside your tests? Isn't the app itself supposed to fire that call? The basic flow would be: 1. Set an expection of your http calls with `$httpBackend` inside your tests. 2. Inject your (for example) controller that fires the http call. 3. Trigger the method that fires the http call. 4. `$httpBackend` will now check if the expection is the same as the fired http request

Comment: first yes it's better use `$httpBackend` development rather than production second I use http request in test for simplicity, there is a remaining question that is that why mock in test and mock in app have conflict with each other?